# How do I deploy a changeset from Sandbox to UAT sandbox to Production?

Tags: deployment, change-set

I want to create a deployment chain where I configure a changeset in a DEV sandbox, deploy to UAT (where it can be tested but not changed) and finally deploy that same changeset from UAT to Production.

The only way that I can see to do that is to re-create the outbound changeset in UAT or alternatively, create a connection from my DEV sandbox to the production sandbox (which I don't really want to do).

Is it possible to set up this 3 tier deployment chain?

Thanks.

Comment: If you familiar with ANT tool .This can be easily done as its a package and just .properties file has to be changed each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot currently redeploy a Changeset as you described. There is an [Idea for this](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000J9NPAA0) that is marked `Under Consideration`. I suggest voting for it.

Answer (score 3):

@MikeChale is correct.  Vote for the [idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000J9NPAA0)!

Here's an alternative process that only uses changesets:

1. Deploy changeset from sandbox to UAT.
2. Clone that changeset to an open changeset in sandbox.
3. Find any errors in UAT.
4. Reproduce and fix errors in sandbox.
5. Create small changeset to push the fix changes to UAT.
6. Add those components to the open changeset in sandbox as well.

At the end of your UAT you will have an open changeset that contains the components that were in the original changeset you pushed plus all of the fixes.  You can then push that to production.  Of course the issue here would be if you made any other changes to components in the changeset in your sandbox that you don't push to UAT and production you might end up moving them production.

Comment: Voted - thanks!  The real issue for me is preventing a package being deployed directly from DEV with the possibility of not going via UAT - thanks again.